# Rest API naming convention, better suggestions?

Tags: rest, api, naming-conventions, naming

I have **endpoints** like following, but couldn't find the best practices for my situation. Do you have better suggestions for following four rest endpoints?

**1. facebook/impression/count**?date_from=01-05-2019&date_to=27-07-2019

```
// returns
{
  "account": "foo",
  "channel": "facebook",
  "value": 4730519
}
```

**2. facebook/fan/count**?date_from=01-05-2019&date_to=27-07-2019

```
// returns
{
  "account": "foo",
  "channel": "facebook",
  "value": 4730519
}
```

**3. facebook/fan/change-rate**?date_from=01-05-2019&date_to=27-07-2019

```
// returns
{
  "account": "foo",
  "channel": "facebook",
  "value": 25
}
```

**4. facebook/video-view/count**?date_from=01-05-2019&date_to=27-07-2019

```
// returns
{
  "account": "foo",
  "channel": "facebook",
  "value": 2512333
}
```

**Second approach may be like this:**

1. **facebook/impression?metric=count**
2. **facebook/fan?metric=count**
3. **facebook/fan?metric=change-rate**
4. **facebook/video?metric=view-count**

Answer (score 1):

> Rest API naming convention, better suggestions?

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your resource identifiers, so long as they are consistent with the production rules laid out in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

So all of your examples are fine.

```
/facebook/impression/count?date_from=01-05-2019&date_to=27-07-2019
/facebook/impression?metric=count&date_from=01-05-2019&date_to=27-07-2019
```

In this case, the tradeoff is one of convenience.  We have [relative resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2) to allow us to reference other identifiers in the same hierarchy, but that is based on *path segments*.

```
/facebook/fan/count + ../change-rate === /facebook/fan/change-rate
```

There is no analogous resolution for the query part -- you have to replace the whole thing.

On the other hand, HTML already has a standard for converting client provided parameters into an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` query string; that can be convenient if you are supporting HTML clients, and want to treat `[change-rate,count,view-count] as parameters provided by the client.

HTTP has built into it [redirection semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4); if you are doing REST, then you can change your mind about the identifier and have the old one support the new.  There's nothing wrong with having two resources that provide the same representations, so that's another option.

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component

What many people prefer (although it isn't strictly necessary) is to reflect the hierarchy of the resources in the spelling of the resource identifiers.  So if the `count` resource is subordinate to the `fan` resource, then `/facebook/fan` and `/facebook/fan/count` reflects the same hierarchy.

But it isn't required -- URL shorteners *work*.

In summary, the machines don't care about domain semantics in the identifiers, so outside of some minor mechanical concerns all of the reasonable human readable spellings are equivalent.